# How do I deploy my Custom MBean into Tomcat 7?

Tags: apache, tomcat7, jmx, mbeans

I have successfully created MBeans and deployed it.  I can also see that my Custom MBean is deployed in MBeans section in JConsole.

How can I deploy it to Tomcat 7?

I found may tutorials online, which are too old.  I have not found any tutorial for Tomcat 7 so far.  Please help me in finding a tutorial which suits Tomcat Version 7.

I used a tutorial which was based on Tomcat 6. But I could not succeed because, one of the listeners used in the Server.xml file "ServerLifecycleListener"  is not used anymore in Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mbeans-descriptors.xml as following and it needs to be placed in same package as the class file it describes.

[Adding MBean descriptions](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/mbeans-descriptor-howto.html)

> ```
> <mbean         name="LDAPRealm"
>         className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ClassNameMBean"
>       description="Custom LDAPRealm"
>            domain="Catalina"
>             group="Realm"
>              type="com.myfirm.mypackage.LDAPRealm">
> <attribute   name="className"
>       description="Fully qualified class name of the managed object"
>              type="java.lang.String"
>         writeable="false"/>
> <attribute   name="debug"
>       description="The debugging detail level for this component"
>              type="int"/>
> .
> .
> ```

You could refer this as well:

[Container level Custom JXM MBean in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473344/container-level-custom-jxm-mbean-in-tomcat-7)