# Container level Custom JXM MBean in Tomcat 7+

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, jmx, tomcat8, mbeans

I need to create a container level JMX MBean for tomcat servers to allow enterprise level monitoring of a few custom features.

The examples I am finding online are focused on webapp level MBeans. I found a few examples for Tomcat 5, but it looks like a lot has changed since then.

How can I register an MBean for an entire Tomcat instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding the required descriptor AND putting a listener in web.xml for the container.  It was necessary to test whether bean already existed in this sceario, since the listener is called for each app in the container.

Answer (score -1):

Tomcat already have MBeans for monitoring stuff. You need to enable it via CATALINA_OPTS, just add:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port={port to access} 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

And then connect to that port via JConsole or VisualVM. Read [further](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/jconsole-jmx-remote-access-on-tomcat/).

Comment: This wasn't the question

Comment: Does not answer the question. The poster wants to add his own mbeans, not learn how to use the JMX properties of the JVM.